# Determine all paths in a directed Activity Network

Tags: python-3.x

I need a simple Python program that determined all paths of the network shown in the diagram.

In the image you see all possible paths.

I tried the code I found for a similar graph but is giving extra paths.

I prefer not to use Networkx for the solution of the problem.